# How can I iterate through a dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, foreach, iteration

I am trying to use a for each statement to iterate through all the values in a dictionary list I created. I would like to be able to print out all the all the values. As well as calling individual values.

```
 Dim dblExpenses = New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
    dblExpenses.Add("Travel_Days", CDbl(txtTravelDays.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Private_Vehicle_Miles", CDbl(txtPrivateVehicleMiles.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Airfare", CDbl(txtAirfare.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Car_Rental_Fees", CDbl(txtCarRentalFees.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Parking_Fees", CDbl(txtParkingFees.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Taxi_Charges", CDbl(txtTaxiCharges.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Registration_Fees", CDbl(txtRegistationFees.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Lodging_Per_Night", CDbl(txtLodgingPerNight.Text))
    dblExpenses.Add("Meals", CDbl(txtMeals.Text))

    For Each item As Double In dblExpenses

    Next
```

Thank you for you help in advance. I did some searching but it I could not find any that use a for each to iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: You need to iterate through the keys collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Double) In dblExpenses
    'item.Key for key
    'item.Value for value
Next
```

Or you can try for only values.

```
For Each item As Double In dblExpenses.Values
    'item
Next
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. Using KeyValuePair is definitely something I should read up on more.

Comment: Give them a Vote on the Up arrow !

Comment: Not enough reputation to do it.